# Time profiling C program in Xcode 7.3

Tags: c, xcode, macos, debugging, profiling

Is it possible to use instruments's Time Profiler on a C program written within Xcode? I've tried opening up Instruments and selecting Time Profiler from within Xcode. The program I want to run it on (my Xcode project) is already selected under "recent executables". However when I press the record button there is no output, it just instantly stops with the pause button greyed out.
Help would be appreciated, thanks.